# Formatting References: Journal Articles with Volume and Number

Tags: biblatex

as I am quite new to LaTeX a friend made most of the presetting. Now I would like to change the reference of a journal article. Now it is:

> Vgl. Jüngling, Clemens: Struktur und Produktion eines Opernhauses und deren wechselseitige Beziehung. In: Zeitschrift für Kulturmanagement 5.1 (2019). S. 91–116.

I would like to have:

> Vgl. Jüngling, Clemens: Struktur und Produktion eines Opernhauses und deren wechselseitige Beziehung. In: Zeitschrift für Kulturmanagement. Jg. 5, Heft 1 (2019). S. 91–116.

(Jg. is the German for Volume and Heft 1 means No. 1).

Is there a way to change that?

```
\documentclass[
11pt, % The default document font size, options: 10pt, 11pt, 12pt
%oneside, % Two side (alternating margins) for binding by default, uncomment to switch to one side
twoside,
%english, 
ngerman, %for German
onehalfspacing, %singlespacing, % Single line spacing, alternatives: onehalfspacing or doublespacing
%draft, % Uncomment to enable draft mode (no pictures, no links, overfull hboxes indicated)
nolistspacing, % If the document is onehalfspacing or doublespacing, uncomment this to set spacing in lists to single
liststotoc, % Uncomment to add the list of figures/tables/etc to the table of contents
%toctotoc, % Uncomment to add the main table of contents to the table of contents
%parskip, % Uncomment to add space between paragraphs
%nohyperref, % Uncomment to not load the hyperref package
headsepline, % Uncomment to get a line under the header
%chapterinoneline, % Uncomment to place the chapter title next to the number on one line
%consistentlayout, % Uncomment to change the layout of the declaration, abstract and acknowledgements pages to match the default layout
xcolor=dvipsnames
]{MastersDoctoralThesis} % The class file specifying the document structure

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international character
\usepackage{microtype} %for better typesetting and readability

\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=small,labelfont=bf,labelsep=endash, labelsep=colon, labelformat=simple]{caption}

\usepackage{wrapfig}






\usepackage{mathpazo} % Use the Palatino font by default

\usepackage[style=footnote-dw, natbib=true, nopublisher=false, urldate=long, citepages=separate, idembib=false, maxbibnames=99]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{remreset}
\makeatletter
\@removefromreset{footnote}{chapter}
\makeatother
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}

\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
    \usebibmacro{name:family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:family-given}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiveni}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:family-given}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \fi
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
  and={u\adddot},
  editor={Hg\adddot},
  editors={Hg\adddot},
  byeditor={hg\adddot\thinspace v\adddotspace},
  thiscite={hier\addcolon\thinspace},
  number={H\adddot},
  }

\renewcommand*\postnotedelim{\addperiod\space}
\renewcommand*{\bibmultinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\bibfinalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\bibrevsdnamedelim}{}
\renewcommand*{\citemultinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\citefinalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\citerevsdnamedelim}{}


\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addperiod\space}
\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addperiod\space}
\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{\addperiod}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgf-pie,stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\\}




\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}


\usepackage[flushmargin]{footmisc}
\addto\captionsngerman{%
  \renewcommand{\figurename}{Abb.}%
  \renewcommand{\tablename}{Tab.}%
}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Keine "Schusterjungen"
    \clubpenalty = 10000
    % Keine "Hurenkinder"
    \widowpenalty = 10000 \displaywidowpenalty = 10000


\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \iflistundef{location}
    {\setunit*{\adddot\space}}
    {\setunit*{\adddot\space}}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\addbibresource{Literaturverzeichnis.bib} % The filename of the bibliography

\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes} % Required to generate language-dependent quotes in the bibliography
```

and:

```
@article{Jungling.2019,
 author = {J{\"u}ngling, Clemens},
 year = {2019},
 title = {Struktur und Produktion eines Opernhauses und deren wechselseitige Beziehung},
 pages = {91--116},
 pagination = {page},
 volume = {5},
 journaltitle = {Zeitschrift f{\"u}r Kulturmanagement},
 number = {1},
 abstract = {}
}
```

Comment: how do you actually include the bibliography? What bibliography style are you using?

Comment: I am using BibLaTeX.

Comment: anyone an idea?

Comment: For future questions you may want to consider posting a compilable example document and not just a bit of your preamble and a `.bib` entry. That makes it much, much easier for others to get started helping you. A compilable example document should reproduce the status quo with as little excess code as possible.

Comment: Do you need all the packages you are loading? `pgfplotstable`, `pgf-pie`, `stackengine`, `arydshln`? Also if it is not too late, I recommend switching from the complex template/class `MastersDoctoralThesis` to a standard or KOMA-Script class.

Comment: Actually, I don't know. A friend of mine preinstalled everything for me as I am new to LaTeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need the following four lines with `biblatex-dw`

```
\renewcommand*{\jourvolstring}{\addperiod\space}
\renewcommand*{\jourvolnumsep}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\bibstring{jourvol}~#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\bibstring{number}~#1}
```

if you change the translation of `number` from `H\addddot` to `Heft`.

`\jourvolstring` is the punctuation before the `volume`. `\jourvolnumsep` is the punctuation between `volume` and `number`. Those commands are specific to `biblatex-dw`. The other two lines just change the field format to include the desired strings (that is standard `biblatex`).

In total (cleaned up MWE)

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  natbib=true, 
  style=footnote-dw,
  maxbibnames=99,
  nopublisher=false,
  urldate=long,
  citepages=separate,
  idembib=false,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}

\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
    \usebibmacro{name:family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:family-given}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiveni}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:family-given}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \fi
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
  and      = {u\adddot},
  editor   = {Hg\adddot},
  editors  = {Hg\adddot},
  byeditor = {hg\adddot\thinspace v\adddotspace},
  thiscite = {hier\addcolon\thinspace},
  number   = {Heft},
}

\renewcommand*\postnotedelim{\addperiod\space}
\renewcommand*{\bibmultinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\bibfinalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\bibrevsdnamedelim}{}
\renewcommand*{\citemultinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\citefinalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\citerevsdnamedelim}{}


\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addperiod\space}
\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addperiod\space}
\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{\addperiod}

\renewcommand*{\jourvolstring}{\addperiod\space}
\renewcommand*{\jourvolnumsep}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\bibstring{jourvol}~#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\bibstring{number}~#1}


\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\adddot\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Jungling.2019,
 author       = {Jüngling, Clemens},
 year         = {2019},
 title        = {Struktur und Produktion eines Opernhauses
                 und deren wechselseitige Beziehung},
 pages        = {91--116},
 pagination   = {page},
 volume       = {5},
 journaltitle = {Zeitschrift für Kulturmanagement},
 number       = {1},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{Jungling.2019}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Jüngling, Clemens: Struktur und Produktion eines Opernhauses und deren wechselseitige Beziehung. In: Zeitschrift für Kulturmanagement. Jg. 5, Heft 1 (2019). S. 91–116.]

Comment: Thank you! It works perfect!. Do you also know how to add a dot between "Kulturmanagement" and "Jg. 5"?

Comment: @qu33ristan Urgh, sorry missed that. See the edit, please.

Comment: awesome! Thank you very much!

Comment: may I ask another question? I have now an article from a magazin which is without Vol. (Jg.) So when I leave it empty now, the whole formatting isn't worknig now anymore. Can you help me again? That would be awesome!

Comment: @qu33ristan Please ask a new question about that with an example entry that shows what is going wrong and explain what you would like to see instead.

Comment: ok, I will do that

Comment: ok, I did so: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/605271/formatting-references-journal-articles-with-volume-and-number-even-if-there-i