# Formatting References: Journal Articles with Volume and Number - even if there is no Volume

Tags: biblatex

I set a new formatting for Journal Articles. The first article by Clemens Jüngling looks like it should be. The second article by Patrick Küpper doesn't include a volume. And I think that brings it to why it looks now different than the other article. Can someone help me, that the second article looks like the same like the first article?

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  natbib=true, 
  style=footnote-dw,
  maxbibnames=99,
  nopublisher=false,
  urldate=long,
  citepages=separate,
  idembib=false,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}

\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
    \usebibmacro{name:family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:family-given}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiveni}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:family-given}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \fi
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
  and      = {u\adddot},
  editor   = {Hg\adddot},
  editors  = {Hg\adddot},
  byeditor = {hg\adddot\thinspace v\adddotspace},
  thiscite = {hier\addcolon\thinspace},
  number   = {Heft},
}

\renewcommand*\postnotedelim{\addperiod\space}
\renewcommand*{\bibmultinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\bibfinalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\bibrevsdnamedelim}{}
\renewcommand*{\citemultinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\citefinalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\citerevsdnamedelim}{}


\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addperiod\space}
\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addperiod\space}
\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{\addperiod}

\renewcommand*{\jourvolstring}{\addperiod\space}
\renewcommand*{\jourvolnumsep}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\bibstring{jourvol}~#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\bibstring{number}~#1}


\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\adddot\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Jungling.2019,
 author       = {Jüngling, Clemens},
 year         = {2019},
 title        = {Struktur und Produktion eines Opernhauses
                 und deren wechselseitige Beziehung},
 pages        = {91--116},
 pagination   = {page},
 volume       = {5},
 journaltitle = {Zeitschrift für Kulturmanagement},
 number       = {1},
}

@article{Kupper.2020,
 author = {K{\"u}pper, Patrick},
 year = {2020},
 title = {Was sind eigentlich l{\"a}ndliche R{\"a}ume?},
 pages = {4--7},
 pagination = {page},
 journaltitle = {Informationen zur politischen Bildung/izpb},
 number = {343},
 abstract = {}
}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
```

Comment: @moewe can you help me?

Comment: For future questions it would be great if you could make the code you post compilable. Almost everything is there, but currently the code is missing a simple `\begin{document}...\end{document}` where you cite the relevant entries and generate a bibliography. Please always test that the code compiles (in a new, empty folder) and produces the output you are asking about before you submit your question.

Comment: And sorry to be a pain, but the two entries cannot look the same in the output because one has a `journal` and the other doesn't. Can you tell us exactly which output you want, please? Note that there are some journals that don't have (traditional) volumes and only identify their issues by year+`number`. But izpb seems to have continuous numbering across years. So keep in mind that the case "missing `volume`" for a journal might need different handling depending on the traditions of the journal.

Comment: The izpb is by issue number (343): there is a PDF of the issue online, you can see on the cover; and also the article itself has its own page: https://www.bpb.de/izpb/laendliche-raeume-343/312687/was-sind-eigentlich-laendliche-raeume   If you want, you could use the year as the volume number. See the web version, which has NR  343/2020 : https://www.bpb.de/izpb/laendliche-raeume-343/

Comment: @moewe OK, thank you for your hints. I am absolutely new to LaTeX and this is the first paper for what I am using LaTeX now. So please excuse my misstakes, I am learning. ;-)
What do you mean by "one has journal and the other doens't"? 
I would like to get:
Vgl. Küpper, Patrick: Was sind eigentlich ländliche Räume? In: Informationen zur politischen Bildung/izpb. Heft 343 (2020). S. 4–7. 
@ Cicada But using the year as volume is also an idea.

Comment: Typo, I meant *one has a `volume` and the other doesn't*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`biblatex-dw` doesn't like `@article` entries with `number` but without a `volume`. One way to resolve this would be to repeat the year as `volume` for these cases, but that duplicates data (unnecessarily).

With a few modifications to the `journal+issuetitle` and `journal+issuetitle+standard` bibmacros you can make `biblatex-dw` accept `@articles` with `number` and without `volume`.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  natbib=true, 
  style=footnote-dw,
  maxbibnames=99,
  nopublisher=false,
  urldate=long,
  citepages=separate,
  idembib=false,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}

\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
    \usebibmacro{name:family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:family-given}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiveni}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:family-given}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \fi
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
  and      = {u\adddot},
  editor   = {Hg\adddot},
  editors  = {Hg\adddot},
  byeditor = {hg\adddot\thinspace v\adddotspace},
  thiscite = {hier\addcolon\thinspace},
  number   = {Heft},
}

\renewcommand*\postnotedelim{\addperiod\space}
\renewcommand*{\bibmultinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\bibfinalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\bibrevsdnamedelim}{}
\renewcommand*{\citemultinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\citefinalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\citerevsdnamedelim}{}


\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addperiod\space}
\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addperiod\space}
\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{\addperiod}

\renewcommand*{\jourvolstring}{\addperiod\space}
\renewcommand*{\jourvolnumsep}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\bibstring{jourvol}~#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\bibstring{number}~#1}


\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\adddot\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{useeditor+others}%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \setunit{\jourvolstring}%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \ifbool{bbx:journumdate}
    {\usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle+date}}
    {\ifbool{bbx:journumafteryear}
      {\usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle+afteryear}}
      {\usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle+standard}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle+standard}{%
  \setunit*{\jourvolnumsep}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{issue+date}}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Jungling.2019,
 author       = {Jüngling, Clemens},
 year         = {2019},
 title        = {Struktur und Produktion eines Opernhauses
                 und deren wechselseitige Beziehung},
 pages        = {91--116},
 volume       = {5},
 journaltitle = {Zeitschrift für Kulturmanagement},
 number       = {1},
}
@article{Kupper.2020,
 author       = {Küpper, Patrick},
 year         = {2020},
 title        = {Was sind eigentlich ländliche Räume?},
 pages        = {4--7},
 journaltitle = {Informationen zur politischen Bildung/izpb},
 number       = {343},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{Jungling.2019,Kupper.2020,sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Küpper, Patrick: Was sind eigentlich ländliche Räume? In: Informationen zur politischen Bildung/izpb. Heft 343 (2020). S. 4–7.]

Comment: You are my savior! thank you!